# Knapsack Algorithm with a O(2^n*n)

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, knapsack-problem

Which algorithm for the knapsack problem has a O(2^n*n) complexity?

I've been asked to implement a solution for the knapsack problem.

I'm familiar with programming but not with asymptotic notation.

Can anybody advise me on which algorithm has a O(2^n*n) complexity?

Answer (score 3):

O(n * 2^n) is the performance of the brute force algorithm (= just try all combinations), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Meet-in-the-Middle_Algorithm